# jQuery not working when used with wordpress menu

Tags: menus, jquery, css

I'm using a starter theme that was provided to me by a friend, and have successfully implemented jQuery several times on the website.  I want a background image inside a div to change when the user click a li in the menu.

```
<ul class="mainNav">
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container' => false, 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
</ul>

$(function(){
$('.menu-item-23').click(function(){
  $('#changeMe').css('background-image','url("../wp-content/themes/theme-name/i/logo4.png")');
});
```

I am able to make this work if I replace .menu-item-23 with other elements on the page - so I know it isn't a file path issue, and I don't think it's the jQuery code.  It seems like I'm not selecting the list item properly, but I have tried dozens of different selectors, (li#menu-item-23, li.menu-item-23, ul.mainNav li#menu-item-23 etc etc)

Comment: First, your jQuery needs to be set to use [noConflict wrappers](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers),

Comment: menus are usually links and will cause a page refresh that will remove your CSS changes.

Answer (score 0):

- You are missing `<script>` tags
- You are using the wrong jQuery variable name. If you want to use the $ alias you need to use noConflict as
  helgatheviking suggested or switch to "jQuery" instead of $
- You are missing }); at the end of the code you posted above
- You should consider separating your JS into a separate file and use wp_enqueue_script in
  the theme's functions or other appropriate theme or plugin PHP file

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Bjorn has some very good points, but I would avoid the javascript entirely, and use css similar to this:

```
.mainNav li:active {
    background-image: transparent url('i/logo4.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Better yet, I would instead target the link itself using `.mainNav a:active`, which suggests your link targets aren't very large and you're using the `li` not the `a` to define the dimensions and size/padding/margin

There's no need for javascript at all here